# Dynamically adding rows under proper section without interfering its sort

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I plan to add holidays (rows) under appropriate separators (months as sections). so far I can retrieve my data from a plist and created sections with predefined theme (for 12 months), But I cannot figure out the right way to add my holidays under appropriate months.

```
@synthesize event, sections;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.event = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2013" ofType:@"plist"]];
    self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    BOOL found;


    for (NSDictionary *oneEvent in self.event)
    {        
        NSString *c = [[oneEvent objectForKey:@"date"] substringToIndex:3];

        found = NO;

        for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
        {
            if ([str isEqualToString:c])
            {
                found = YES;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {     
            [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
    }


    for (NSDictionary *oneEvent in self.event)
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:[[oneEvent objectForKey:@"date"] substringToIndex:3]] addObject:oneEvent];
    }    


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return [[self.sections allKeys] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *months = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"January",@"February",@"March",@"April",@"May",@"June",@"July",@"August",@"September",@"October",@"November",@"December", nil];
    return [months objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [[self.sections valueForKey:[[self.sections allKeys]  objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *results = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[self.sections allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [results  objectForKey:@"date"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [results objectForKey:@"event"];

    return cell;
}
```

Current Result :

[image: result]

Comment: Check out `-[NSArray indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:]`

Answer (score 1):

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method you are assuming that [self.sections allKeys] has the same ordering as your hardcoded "months" array.  One way to fix this is to keep the "months" array around as a property, then change that line to this:

```
NSDictionary *results = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[self.months objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] substringToIndex:3]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Probably a better way would be to store everything in an array instead of a dictionary. I'd probably use an array of 12 dictionaries, each of which has "month" and "holidays" fields.  Something like this:

```
self.sections = @[ @{@"month":@"January",@"holidays":@[…]}, @{@"month":@"February",@"holidays":@[…]},...]
```